# Frames and IE9-unable to recogize objects

Tags: webdriver

I am working on trying to click a button in a popup  window -works in firefox but the usual does not work in IE. The popup seems to be frames as in firefox when you right click on the pane the frames options appears

Here is the code that works in firefox but in IE it fails  when you switchto().frame.

```
Set<String> Windowid = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> iter = Windowid.iterator();
String MainWindow = iter.next();
System.out.println(MainWindow);
String DeptWindow = iter.next();
System.out.println(DeptWindow);
driver.switchTo().window(DeptWindow);
String CurrentWindow = driver.getTitle();
System.out.println(CurrentWindow
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("onclick=GetDept()");// change DEPT
driver.switchTo().frame("TreeButtons"); // switch to top frame
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@id='DLG_OK']")).click();
```

I have tried using the below but again seems to work in firefox but not IE

```
WebElement makemytripsearch_btn =(WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('DLG_OK');");
//makemytripsearch_btn.getText();
//System.out.println(makemytripsearch_btn.getText());
 makemytripsearch_btn.click();
```

Where should I go from here. IE is always trouble with a capital T

Hi,

In Firefox here is the source code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <HTML>
    <HEAD><TITLE>Department Selection</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <FRAMESET BORDER=1 BORDERCOLOR="black" FRAMESPACING=0 ROWS="*,60" OnLoad="opener.PopulateFrames()">
    <FRAME MARGINHEIGHT=0 MARGINWIDTH=2 NORESIZE SCROLLING="AUTO" ID="TreeSelect" NAME="TreeSelect" SRC="blank.htm">
    <FRAME MARGINHEIGHT=7 MARGINWIDTH=10 NORESIZE SCROLLING="NO" ID="TreeButtons" NAME="TreeButtons" SRC="blank.htm">
    <NOFRAMES>
    <BODY><H1 Align=CENTER>Clockwise access issue</H1>
    <P>You do not have FRAMES enabled, please contact your administrator</P></BODY></NOFRAMES>
    </FRAMESET></HTML>

In IE however he is the source code

!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Department Selection</TITLE>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--
table {margin:0;}
#WaitLayer {position:absolute; top:5; left:7; visibility:hidden; zIndex:3};
-->
</STYLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
function Showlayer(lShowit) {WaitLayer.style.visibility =       (lShowit?"visible":"hidden");}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR=#ECE9D8><FORM METHOD="POST" NAME="ButtonForm" onSubmit="return false;">
<TABLE COLS=1 ROWS=1 BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 ALIGN="RIGHT"><TR><TD NOWRAP ALIGN="RIGHT">
<img src="images/dlg_ok.gif?Lang=6153" name="DLG_OK" ID="DLG_OK" width=89 height=33 onClick="return window.parent.opener.DeptSelected()
" onMouseOver="window.status='OK';document.getElementById('DLG_OK').src='images/dlu_ok.gif?Lang=6153';return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';document.getElementById('DLG_OK').src='images/dlg_ok.gif?Lang=6153';return true;" onMouseDown="window.status='';document.getElementById('DLG_OK').src='images/dlm_ok.gif?Lang=6153';return true;" onMouseUp="window.status='';document.getElementById('DLG_OK').src='images/dlg_ok.gif?Lang=6153';return true;">&nbsp;<img src="images/dlg_cncl.gif?Lang=6153" name="DLG_CANCEL" ID="DLG_CANCEL" width=89 height=33 onClick="return window.parent.opener.CloseDeptPopup()
" onMouseOver="window.status='Cancel';document.getElementById('DLG_CANCEL').src='images/dlu_cncl.gif?Lang=6153';return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';document.getElementById('DLG_CANCEL').src='images/dlg_cncl.gif?Lang=6153';return true;" onMouseDown="window.status='';document.getElementById('DLG_CANCEL').src='images/dlm_cncl.gif?Lang=6153';return true;" onMouseUp="window.status='';document.getElementById('DLG_CANCEL').src='images/dlg_cncl.gif?Lang=6153';return true;">&nbsp;
</TD></TR></TABLE></FORM>
<SPAN ID="WaitLayer"><H2>Please Wait</H2></SPAN>
</BODY></HTML>

Everything work fine until this line of code below in which Firefox behaves but IE is unable to find the button

driver.switchTo().frame("

TreeButtons"); // switch to top frame
```

Comment: Not an issue with Selenium. If your page is rendering differently in IE, which it is, then talk to your dev's.

Comment: Hi,it seems not be any frames at all in IE but in firefox it does appear so rather than saying it is not a problem with selenium even though I used java script as an alternatively I would like so know what and why this is the case and what code should I use to access the button in IE

Comment: Hi, here again well I do not think IE has frames as the source code does not mention frameset or frames anywhere, is is possible for firefox to show frames and then IE to not have any frames -- does this mean that in IE I do not have to worry about frames when writing my code as I do in firefox please explain as I am bit lost with this?